# Check for element being present then check if its displayed

Tags: promise, protractor

I need to check if the pop up exists, if it does then I need to check if its displayed then perform certain action on it.

I have implemented the below. I was wanting to know if there is any better way of achieving this.

```
 licenseUpdate.isPresent().then(function (item) {

                if (item == true) {
                    licenseUpdate.isDisplayed().then(function (res) {

                        if (res == true){

                            licenseUpdate.click();
                        };
                         });

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using page object (you should) you can write something like this:

```
clickLicenseUpdate() {
    const licenseUpdate = $(licenseUpdateCssSelector);

    return licenseUpdate.isPresent()
        .then((isPresent) => {
            if (!isPresent) { return false; }

            return licenseUpdate.isDisplayed();
        })
        .then((isDisplayed) => {
            if (!isDisplayed) { return false; }

            return licenseUpdate.click().then(() => true);
        })
}
```

Note that if you are using and old JS version (you shouldn't) you need to replace arrow functions with traditional anonymous functions.

Some helpful links about Page Object Design Pattern:

[PageObjects](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

[Martin Fowler PageObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)

Code explained (or at least, that is the plan):

- Using `$` to locate an element but you can use any strategy
  supported by Protractor.
  `browser.findElement(by.className('license'))` equivalent to
  `$('license')`, `browser.findElement(by.id('license'))` equivalent to
  `$('#license')`. Check [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) documentation for more examples.
- Once you a have found a web element that match your locator, you can
  use `isPresent` method to determine whether the element is present on
  the page. `isPresent` returns a promise that resolve to a boolean
  value.
- `then` always return a promise. You can return a primitive value from
  `onFulfilled` callback and that value would be cast to a promise with
  resolve with same value. That is what is done here:  `if (!isPresent) { return false; }`;  or you can return another promise
  from `onFulfilled` callback and the promise returned by `then` will be resolved or rejected with same value of returned promise. 
  That is what is done here: `return licenseUpdate.isDisplayed();`. `isDisplayed()` also return a
  promise that will resolve with whether this element is currently
  visible on the page.

  This can be a bit overwhelming if you are not
  used to deal with promises. Check this out [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)
- Finally, if the element is present and is displayed, click the element with the`click` method that, surprise, also return a
  promise ([WebDriverJS API is based on promises](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md)).
- Note that if element is not present, `isPresent` is false in this
  line `if (!isPresent)`, returning false immediately bypass
  `licenseUpdate.isDisplayed()` execution and resolve with a false value. In that
  case `isDisplayed` value is false and again false is returned
  immediately bypassing the `licenseUpdate.click()` execution.
- Also note that `clickLicenseUpdate` return a promise that will
  resolve to false if the element is not present or if is present but not
  displayed. To keep `clickLicenseUpdate` returned value consistent, I recommend you to wait for `licenseUpdate.click()` and then return a boolean value as it is done here: `return licenseUpdate.click().then(() => true);` ([using implicit return from arrow functions](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-arrow-functions-in-depth)) because promise returned by `click()` resolve with a void value. 
  That is harmless but is considered a good practice maintain a consistent return value, always a boolean value, not sometime a boolean and others a void value.

Comment: I'm pretty novice in javascript, I'll try and implement this. Thanks and yes I am using Page Objects.

Comment: Yes plz, that would be of great help.